# Class Variable Not Found When Debugging

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm currently using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. When debugging my program, I'm running into an odd issue. When mousing over a class variable, instead of showing the value of it, nothing pops up. I then tried creating a watch for the variable. Instead of finding the variable, the value displayed in the Watch window simply says: "class "`class`" has no member "`variable name`". Here is a screenshot to demonstrate what I'm describing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbBqC.png

As shown here, the variable m_lineProgramID's value is unable to be displayed in the watch screen. None of the variables that start with m_line are found in the local variables list, yet the line "m_lineProgramID = 0;" doesn't cause an issue. In addition, I tried adding the variable to the constructor's initialization list and initialize it to 0, which also does not cause an issue.

Edit: Just to add a little extra info. I am compiling my program in Debug mode as a 64-bit executable. I've made sure to get 64-bit versions of the libraries I use and have not had an issue running my program until now. Additionally, I renamed both the class and the header & implementation files. I now get a new error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utsli.png

Edit 2: I figured out the error that was causing the "Internal Error". I was storing my class in a std::map, and forgot to change the name when using std::make_pair to add an entry (although the class name was correct when I defined the map). This fixed the C1001 error I got and renaming the class and files seems to have fixed the original issue. If anyone could shed some light on why I had the issue in the first place, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Are you running it under release mode?

Comment: I'm running it in Debug Mode.